# File not found at path in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an image within the public/badges directory called 1.png - I am trying to use the Storage library in laravel but keep getting the following error even though the file does exist at that location:

// Error

```
FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 381:
File not found at path: Users/gk/Sites/mysite/public/badges/1.png
```

// Code

```
$filePath = 'badges/1.png';
$path = public_path()."/".$filePath
Storage::disk('local')->get($path);
dd($contents);
```

Comment: you can use this {!! Html::image('badges/1.png') !!}

Comment: What your aim? you want to output the file to end users?

Comment: @salar i want to get the file and then copy it to a different location so the Html::image won't work for me in this instance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Form Laravel 5.2 documentation:

> When using the local driver, note that all file operations are relative to the root directory defined in your configuration file. By default, this value is set to the storage/app directory.

So You are looking for file in: `storage/app/Users/gk/Sites/mysite/public/badges/1.png`

Error is quite confusing.

**[Update]**

Add to `config/filesystems.php`

```
'disks' => [

    //... 

    'local_public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path(),
    ],

    //... 
],
```

then

```
$filePath = 'badges/1.png';
$content = Storage::disk('local_public')->get($filePath);
dd($content);
```

Comment: I am trying to get the file from the public/badges directory which i'll then run a script to rename each file, just unsure why I get the error as my paths seem correct.

Comment: create file in path which i show You and You'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Python - that seems to work... I am clearly getting mixed up with how it works..
I want to have these images 'stored' within the public/badges directory rather than the 'Storage' directory (which i've not really figured out yet...) But thanks i am getting closer to my goal :)

Comment: @Python Perfect.. just perfect! :)

Comment: It's my pleasure. :)

Comment: anyone know how to get a full path of the file rather get the file content? I have to generate a md5 key from the file.

Comment: It solved my problem and save my day as I use the local disk to test~I what to ask anothere question is if not have the question if I use the true url web site on line? just use Storage::move(public_path().oldfile.jpg,public_path().newfile.jpg) , no need change the config/filesystems.php? @Pyton

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in Laravel 5.7, this fix my problem:

```
php artisan storage:link
```